# I'm getting 'Name is not defined' in python when referencing a package I made and installed with 'distribution'

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, package, distribute

I'm trying to test packaging scripts and installing them for future use. I created a script 'my_script.py' and then installed it with 
`python docs\setup.py develop` Which seems to have worked, as I got all the successful install lines. This code contained this:

```
class test(object):

    def test_print(self, tool):

        for i in tool:
            print i
```

Then I created a script that says:

```
from my_script import test

tool = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

test_print(self, tool)
```

and it's returning :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin\test2.py", line 5, in <module>
    test_print(self, tool)
NameError: name 'test_print' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming the import works, it should still be `test().test_print(tool)`. `test_print` is an instance method of the class `test`. Also you don't pass the `self` arguement, it's only used within the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition **test_print** is a method from the test class. So you have to instanciate an object before to use it:

```
from my_script import test

tool = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

testObj = test()
testObj.test_print(tool)
```

Otherwise it is also possible to add a [@staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator to define a method as a static.

```
class test(object):
    @staticmethod
    def test_print(tool):
        for i in tool:
            print i

 from my_script import test

 tool = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
 test.test_print(tool)
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense and works like a charm!